# javax.el.ELException: Failed to parse the expression [${ofn:storeLookup(${bundleDetailsMap['bundleStoreUnit']})}]

Tags: javascript, java, spring, jsp, tomcat

I am Trying to call a JSTL Function with El Expression parameter but it is throwing runtime exception,

```
enter code here<c:forEach var="bundleDetailsMap" items="${orderSummaryInfo.pickupBundleDetails}">
                            {
                                name: "${bundleDetailsMap['name']}",
                                price: "${bundleDetailsMap['price']}",

                                <c:set var="store" value="${ofn:storeLookup(${bundleDetailsMap['bundleStoreUnit']})}"  />
                                        storeName: "${store.storeName}",
                                        storeAddress: "${store.streetAddr}",
                                        storeCity: "${store.city}",
                                        storeState: "${store.state}",
                                        storeZip: "${store.zipForDisplay}",
                                        storeUnit: "${store.unit}",
                                        monFriHours: "${store.monHours}",
                                        satHours: "${store.satHours}",
                                        sunHours: "${store.sunHours}",
                                items: [
                                    <c:forEach var="bundleItem" items="${bundleDetailsMap['items']}">
                                        {
                                            src: "${bundleItem.imageDescription}",
                                            bundleName: "${bundleItem.itemName}",
                                            qty: "${bundleItem.quantity}",
                                            ashleyStoreUnit : "${bundleItem.ashleyStoreUnit}",
                                        },
                                    </c:forEach>
                                ],
                            },
                        </c:forEach>
```

in this  is throwing parse error

Comment: in the above code <c:set var="store" value="${ofn:storeLookup(${bundleDetailsMap['bundleStoreUnit']})}"  /> is throwing parse error

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is in `${ofn:storeLookup(${bundleDetailsMap['bundleStoreUnit']})}`.

I don't think you are allowed to make such complicated calls in EL.

You should try setting the EL variable in your controller, or try using scriptlets to acomplish this.

Comment: Actually I am getting that ${bundleDetailsMap['bundleStoreUnit']} from a loop of List<Map>'s so i cant set that in the controller

Comment: Well, you've set the `orderSummaryInfo.pickupBundleDetails` in the controller. So, you can try using the EL var instead of JSTL var `bundleDetailsMap`.
Try `value="${ofn:storeLookup(${orderSummaryInfo.pickupBundleDetails['bundleStoreUnit']})}"`

Comment: I am pretty much new to Jsp can you ellaborate

Comment: Got it like this<c:set var="storeUnit" value="${bundleDetailsMap['bundleStoreUnit']}" />
         <c:set var="store" value="${ofn:storeLookup(storeUnit)}"  />